# ¿Puedo generar un PHP único para todos los productos de una página? ¿Afecta el SEO?

Tags: php, seo

Estoy creando una página con PHP. Tengo un listado de 48 productos diferentes que son generados dinámicamente a partir de los registros de la base de datos.

Mi pregunta es: cada ítem de la lista tiene un enlace único pero la página es igual para todos, solo cambian imágenes e información. Entonces ¿puedo generar una página .php y hacer que los 48 productos usen la misma y que solo cambie la información o tengo que crear las 48 paginas? ¿Eso afecta el SEO?

Comment: Las rutas o url tienen que ser diferentes midominio.com/listado.php?id=1 sería lo mas común, aunque te recomiendo que utilizando htaccess hagas rutas amigables midominio.com/barco/nombre-del-barco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solo puedes sino que es lo más aconsejable crear una única página con contenido dinámico, en la cual implementes el contenido con variables, ya que necesitas menos código y es mucho más fácil implementar cambios de cara a futuros desarrollos.
En cuanto al seo, también deberias utilizar elementos dinámicos que se adapten a los productos, ya que igual que con el contenido, puedes utilizar variables dinámicas en PHP para rellenar por ejemplo los metas de las páginas. Desde el punto de vista del seo, debes pensar si tus 48 productos son totalmente independientes o deben estructurarse en grupos, por ejemplo si fueran animales:

Perros/pequeños

Perros/grandes

Esto se puede reflejar en urls distintas que van a la misma página PHP. Puedes manejarlas para hacerlas más amigables en el htaccess de tu proyecto.

Comment: Bueno, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy haciendo una pagina de venta de barcos y creo que no necesito crear grupos porque los 48 productos son barcos. Mi otra duda es si yo creo un solo archivo .php el Google va a ver mis 48 paginas o solo genera las paginas si la persona acceder mi sitio web ? o tiene que hacer una configuracion adicional?

Comment: Google ve tus 48 páginas, por eso debes hacer dinámicos también los metas, para él son 48 porque el contenido va a ser distinto. Procura añadir descripciones diferentes en la medida de lo posible.

Answer (score 0):

puedes realizar una sola pagina para el mismo, pues es contenido dinámico que estas usando que es igual en todos los sentidos aunque cambie el id o otros datos los parámetros son iguales.

Ejemplo suponiendo que tienes un producto que tenga una imagen, un nombre y un precio y quieres mostrarlo entonces puedes crearte una pagina .php de la siguiente manera

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3><?php $item->nombre_producto; ?>
        <figure>
            <img src="<?php $item->imagen; ?>" />
        </figure>
        <span><strong>Precio: </strong> <?php $item->precio; ?></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

En el ejemplo ves como queda tu pagina .php, aquí estas enviando los datos para mostrarlos en una variable llamada $item que la misma es una objeto que tiene los datos nombre, imagen y precio y quedaría así.

Comment: Bueno, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy haciendo una pagina de venta de barcos y creo que no necesito crear grupos porque los 48 productos son barcos. Mi otra duda es si yo creo un solo archivo .php el Google va a ver mis 48 paginas o solo genera las paginas si la persona acceder mi sitio web ? o tiene que hacer una configuracion adicional?